# Why is BluetoothSocket.connect() called before Toast.makeText().show()?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-toast

I'm trying to show a Toast message right before attempting to connect to a `Bluetooth` device that I've selected from my ListView, but the problem is that the `Toast` message appears after connecting so that the user can know whether their device is currently attempting to connect to selected BT device. It's supposed to be like so:

- Device selected from `ListView`
- Toast message: "Connecting..."
- `btSocket.connect()` has been called and has made a successful connection
- Toast message: "Connected!"

Instead, it happens like this:

- Device selected from `ListView`
- `btSocket.connect()` has been called and has made a successful connection
- Toast message: "Connected!"
- Toast message: "Connecting..."

Note that the app freezes when attempting to connect to the `btSocket` then unfreezes and continues its work.

Example code:

```
listView_myDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        BluetoothSocket btSocket;

        // ... Determine which device is selected, etc.

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        btSocket.connect();

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // ...
    }
```

});

Comment: I have no clear understanding with your this statement "Device is connected" ..where it is coming from?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I have edited my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: are you sure you have share complete code of onItemClick event?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I don't think It's necessary. Everything gets called without a problem. I've confirmed that using breakpoints, but after the `Connecting...` message gets called, it doesn't appear, it gets stuck on the `btSocket.connect();`, makes the connection and calls the `Connected!` toast, but then calls the `Connecting...` toast afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that connection might take little bit time and you have to make sure that Toast-CONNECTED trigger ONLY after it is connected. The fastest solution but NOT BEST will be

```
BluetoothSocket btSocket;
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btSocket.connect();


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (btSocket.isConnected()){
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }            }
    }, 5000);
```

So you give time for connection and checking it after 5 seconds

Comment: But `Connected!` is not a problem. It shows after connecting to the device, which is what I want. The problem is `Connecting...` not showing before `btSocket.connect()`, but rather after `Connected!`.

Comment: Well, your code works, but `Connecting...` still gets called after `btSocket.connect()`.

Comment: @wEight does sign CONNECTED appears ?

Comment: Yes, but `Connecting...` appears AFTER `btSocket.connect()` and not BEFORE.

Comment: First of all please explain what do you need to show right way TOASTS? the method btSocket.connect() does not have UI part and dont have callback. So what is the purpose of connecting ui toast with non ui connect method? What is the main goal of this manipulation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning android development. I'm just trying to let a user know that their device is connecting to the selected BT device from the `ListView`, without manipulating the `ListView` itself. Do you think that there's a better way to do this?

Comment: No problem. Thats why im trying to help. So first of all toast-CONNECTING no need to connect to connect method because they are starting at the same time. The main thing is to make sure that TOASTS are going the right order. So it suppose to be click->Connecting->ConnectED ... is it like this right now?

Comment: Yes, Toasts are going in the right order. Your code works.

Comment: thats it. there can be better solution from point of view of architecture but for now i think this one is best. If you find it helpful could you mark it as answer?

Comment: Well, thanks for you time, but I can't because my issue has not been resolved. I still need to know how to make the `Connecting` sign appear before `btSocket.connect()` if it is possible in any way, if not then an alternative solution. If you have one, you can post another answer. I will update my post giving more detail that I want the user to know when their device is connecting to the BT device. The app freezing can be a sign but I prefer adding some visualisation instead. You'll get an upvote, though. :)

Comment: btw i dont get it what is the point of Connecting sign appear before btSocket.connect()... rly... but good luck

Comment: Well, here's an example. A user who is using my app for the first time could be confused. For example, they select a BT device from the list they want to connect to, but nothing appears and the app freezes a bit while the device is actually connecting. That could be confusing and make the user tap on it multiple times creating multiple unnecessary calls. I am thinking of adding like a loading circle animation and suspending touch, but I have trouble understanding how everything works, so I don't wanna add unecessary code I'm not sure they work propely. Like Toast to begin with. Also thanks! :)

Comment: ahhhh.... i know... the problem might be in the following... you are connecting device in the main thread. thats why its freezing.... to avoid that you have to connect it in separate thread as said in the documentation... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#java  so better show all code ill tell you what to do

Comment: Well, first of all, so sorry for late reply, I've had other things to do, then came back to this and remembered about this question and answer. It makes so much sense to me. Thank you. :)